# CONVERT .AU file TO .OGG file

Tags: audio, converters

I want to convert .au file to .ogg file using shell. I have found oggconvert but it works as GUI not on the shell. I am having an client server application . The client will send me .au sound file. On the server , I want to convert it to .ogg file. I m using Ruby on Rails as server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Usage: `sox sourcefile.au targetfile.ogg` It just works.